# Using 24.01 Android gradle error

Tags: android

I got this error because of lower version in `SDK`.

```
 Manifest merger failed : Attribute
 meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from
 [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1]
 AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 is also present at
 [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1]
 AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1). Suggestion: add
 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at
 AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.
```

Comment: Add gradle file also so we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a supported library version whatever available in your SDK. its give a suggestion in build.gradle file of your app.